# backup date weekly,monthly,quarterly in php

Tags: php, date, backup

I want to create a backup script to automatically  run 3 times: monday of every week,first day of 1 of each month,and once per 3 months.My logical thinking,isnt that good,so i need your help guys.The code has to be in php,and the easiest way is with if.

Comment: use a cron job (if you have a linux based system you're running the php script on) or a scheduled task (windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do a `cron job` or `launchd` to do the automation but you could have it run your PHP script without a problem. All it would do is a directory recursive iterator to copy and make directories in a backup location. PHP has a ZIP library, if installed on your server, to create compressed files if so desired. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php). This could be as complex a you make it. You may want to store the files on a remote server which you could use the [FTP features](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) in php to send with.

Comment: you didnt get it dont you? I dont need to find out how to create a backup script,i just need some help with some "if" logic

Comment: Well in the `cron` settings, you would set when it needs to run the PHP script. There wouldn't be any real "if" logic in the PHP script aside from checking if there is a directory structure to copy from and if there is a place to copy to. Other than that, the script would be straight forward. Are you using a `cron job` for the automation?

Comment: no,dude,i want to use just php

Comment: You can use PHP to do the actions but you can't trigger your PHP script without a load action like a browser refresh/load or an automation processing application, so you need to use something like a `cron` or `launchd` job to run the PHP script. PHP alone can not do what you want.

Comment: really? because its kinda work,i mean comeone im not so skilled in php,but.... yes you need something to trigger the script,thats why you can create an index php file with a connection to database,or you can create a submit button and use isset to trigger the backup,aint that hard uh?